# I know my root password, so where do i type it to open this file?

Tags: kernel, permissions, root

I have my root password, and just installed a keylogger for myself and after losing a long chunk of text i worked really hard on to a program crash. The keylogger installed just fine, using my root password in the terminal worked fine to, set the output file and started it.
Now how do i look at the output file? Under permissions, it say's that only root can read/write. How do i log in as root?

Comment: That is annoying indeed. It should ask if you want to open as administrator when you are in the admin group. Perhaps we can get it in 12.10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't start a file browser instance with gksu to open a file.  I would use:

```
gksudo gedit /the/full/path/to/the/file
```

Or any other text editor it's easy to copy paste multi-page text from for that matter.

Comment: No problem.  Do be careful with bouncing about as root though.  Some editors save preference files that might get re-written as root and you can have problems down the road.

Answer (score 4):

**Enable open as administrator in nautilus!**

To get started, press Ctrl – Alt – T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

enter code here

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-gksu
```

[image]

After installing that application run copy and paste the line below and press enter.

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/libnautilus-gksu.so /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/
```

[image]

Finally, log out and back in then go and test it, by clicking your right mouse click on the file you want to run as Admin and your see a popup menu with the words: open as administrater.

[image]

Visit: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/12/add-open-as-administrator-to-nautilus-context-menu-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/ for help and from here.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

First, Open Terminal
Type:

```
gksu nautilus <location>
```

will help to navigate as root.

```
sudo gedit <location>
```

will help to open / edit too.

Comment: Won't Gedit automatically be run as root if you run Nautilus as root and use it to open a file?